# Aggregate (concatenate, join, merge, zip, addrange) two lists of data rows, but put a slash (or another sign) between the aggregated data in the row

Tags: c#

Is it possible to aggregate two lists of data rows, but put a slash between the data from the 1st list and the data from the 2nd list, please?

These are my lists of data rows:

TargetVariableList tdListCoreAggregated = tdListCore.Aggregated();

TargetVariableList tdListDivisionAggregated = tdListDivision.Aggregated();

I tried this below, but I suppose it is for a data row, not a data table, so it doesn't work.

```
DataTable dtCoreDivision = (DataTable)tdListCoreAggregated.Data.AsEnumerable()
    .Zip(tdListDivisionAggregated.Data.AsEnumerable(), (a, b) => a + " | " + b);
```

Comment: What is a `TargetVariableList`, does it inherit `DataTable`? If you `Zip` those together you'd expect `a` and `b` to be `DataRow`s, without an idea of the schema of data in each `DataTable` and the columns you are interested in it is not possible to answer your question. Are you asking or all the data in each row?

Comment: @Jodrell Yes, it inherits DataTable. Yes, I want all the data in each row. And thank you for your interest very much.

Comment: That makes sense, so then, do you want the columns of each `DataTable` aggregated into one result or a different delimiter for rows and columns? If you want an aggregated or joined result, what would you like to do with columns that share a name, can they have different values or, are all the columns guaranteed to have different names?

Comment: @Jodrell It is actually 2 DataTables, created from the original DataTable using the Where condition. So I want to aggregate the columns into 1 result and they have the same name.

Comment: So, all the columns will match, what happens when they have different values, should some values be summed?

Comment: @Jodrell Or I'm thinking if the two DataTables could be used as the DataSource for the respective comboBox and its DisplayMember would display the slash. But I don't know if it is possible.

Comment: @Jodrell No, those values should appear next to each other. E.g. 2 and 2 should be 2 | 2 in the row.

Comment: I see, do you'd like the output to be a new `DataTable`.

Comment: @Jodrell Yes, I would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this, you can [see it working here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/A3m2Vj).

```
public static DataTable Zip(
    this DataTable source,
    DataTable other,
    string delimiter = "|")
{
    var result = new DataTable();
    foreach(DataColumn column in source.Columns)
    {
        result.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName, typeof(string));  
    }

    var sourceEnum = source.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator();
    var otherEnum = other.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator();

    while(sourceEnum.MoveNext() && otherEnum.MoveNext())
    {
        var newRow = result.NewRow();
        foreach(DataColumn column in source.Columns)
        {
            var sourceValue = sourceEnum.Current[column.ColumnName].ToString();
            var otherValue = otherEnum.Current[column.ColumnName].ToString();
            newRow[column.ColumnName] =
                $"{sourceValue}{delimiter}{otherValue}";
        }

        result.Rows.Add(newRow);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But I tried it and found out I was thinking wrong. A new table can't be returned - I've lost the data. Also, not only strings must be returned, but also integers. In the beginning, there is a stored procedure, a PostgreSQL function that returns a table with columns. One column contains data in JSON format. In order to use the data from this column for displaying e.g. in individual comboboxes, a table was created in the c# application, where both the original columns and the new columns from the JSON data are present, as well as all occurring combinations...

Comment: ...However, for the purpose of displaying selected columns in comboboxes, their rows were also aggregated. But now I needed to split that table with aggregated values into 2 according to a certain condition (1 column contains "core" and "division" values, so according to that condition) and display the selected row of a certain column in the combobox as e.g.: version 1 + version 1 | version 1. (The original display is version 1 + version 1 + version 1).

Comment: @Jana, you can see why its important to clarify what is required before going to the effort of providing a solution. So, after teasing out what you wanted in the comments, I think this is the answer to your original question. Now that you've got the "straw man" of what you asked for, you've realized you want something else. I'd suggest you ask another question, [being clear about what you need in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), the question my get upvoted, then review this answer from the perspective of the original question.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. It's my beginner's mistake, but I hope to learn. Anyway, I appreciate your guidance very much.

Comment: @Jana, you could link the revised question here. A well structured question has a better change of either, being matched with an existing question, and it's answers or, being useful to future visitors.

Comment: I tried to ask better there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74809817/aggregate-concatenate-join-merge-zip-addrange-rows-of-two-datatables-but