# Aggregate (concatenate, join, merge, zip, addrange) columns of two DataTables, but put a slash (or another sign) between them

Tags: c#

Is it possible to aggregate columns of two DaTatables, but put a slash between them, please?

These are the DataTables:

TargetVariableList tdListCoreAggregated = tdListCore.Aggregated();

TargetVariableList tdListDivisionAggregated = tdListDivision.Aggregated();

I tried this below, but I suppose it is for a DataRow, not a DataTable, so it doesn't work.

```
DataTable dtCoreDivision = (DataTable)tdListCoreAggregated.Data.AsEnumerable()
.Zip(tdListDivisionAggregated.Data.AsEnumerable(), (a, b) => a + " | " + b);
```

Simple Concat as below works, but it doesn't do what I want (no slash, of course):

```
DataTable dtCoreDivision = tdListCoreAggregated.Data.AsEnumerable()
.Concat(tdListDivisionAggregated.Data.AsEnumerable())
.CopyToDataTable();
```

Or Merge:

```
tdListCoreAggregated.Data.Merge(tdListDivisionAggregated.Data);
```

To be more specific: A new table can't be returned - I lost the data when I tried. Also, not only strings must be returned, but also integers.

In the very beginning, there is a stored procedure, a PostgreSQL function that returns a table with columns. One column contains data in JSON format. In order to use the data from this column for displaying e.g. in individual ComboBoxes, a table was created in the c# application, where both the original columns and the new columns with  the JSON data are present, as well as all occurring combinations. However, for the purpose of displaying selected columns in ComboBoxes, their rows were also aggregated. But now I needed to split that table with aggregated values into 2 according to a certain condition (the "ldsity_object_type_label_cz" column contains rows with "core" or "division" values, so according to that condition) and display the selected row of a certain column in the ComboBox as e.g.: version 1 + version 1 | version 1. (The original display is version 1 + version 1 + version 1).

I am also thinking to adjust the class with the original table (not divided into 2, yet, see the link below), but I'm not successful to write Where (something like ldsity_object_type_label_cz == "core" and  ldsity_object_type_label_cz == "division") there.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/100I_aKNMzTFVexzHOrvyQncgtgCgYDOj/view?usp=sharing

Picture of the original, undivided, extended table with all JSON data combinations:
[extended table with all JSON data combinations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47pjl.jpg)

Picture of the original, undivided, extended table with aggregated rows:
[extended table with aggregated rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08NHZ.jpg)

Comment: So, you want to combine two `DataTable`'s , what are the rules for how the columns should be combined? Should the columns be mapped together by name? When there is no map, should the data appear sparsely populated in the result? When the columns do map, what are the rules for how the data should be combined?

Comment: @Jodrell Yes, I think the columns should be mapped together by name. There is a column called "target_variable_id" with unique ids. I display the value (cell) in the ComboBox according to the selected value (cell) from the "indicator_label_cz" column. I added images of the original, undivided table in the question to understand better. And come to think of it, I want to aggregate columns, not rows! I need to edit the question. I'm so sorry!